# How do I group my web parts in the "add web parts" dialog

Tags: sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

I am attempting to group my custom web parts together in the "Add Web Parts" dialog that appears when you click "Add a Web Part".  Currently the web parts are scattered around the Miscellaneous section.

This web page: http://claytonj.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/how-to-add-a-webpart-into-a-special-group-other-than-miscellaneous/ describes how to do so by modifying the element manifest (in my case, WebPart1.xml) but I am getting no success with this method.

I want to avoid 1) making the changes via the standard SP interface since that would require adding the groups for several web parts on 50+ site collections , and 2) making the changes programmatically, if possible.

Is this functionality actually broken?  Has anyone else gotten this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the method in the link I posted does work, but if you're updating an existing web part than the existing web part will not get the new properties until you delete and re-add it to the gallery.